# Seleceted Value from a ListBox WPF .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, listbox

I have a listbox in my WPF app. The definition is given below:

```
<ListBox Margin="17.493,33.32,22.491,26.656" Name="lstData"   
                 PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_MouseDown"
                 IsTextSearchEnabled="False" />
```

In the code behind, I bind the ListBox to a List. When the value is selected from the List Box, in my code behind, I want to be able to retrieve that value. How do I do it? Sample C# code will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just bind to an item in your code behind

Example:

```
<ListBox Margin="17.493,33.32,22.491,26.656" Name="lstData"   
         SelectionChanged="ListBox_selectionChanged"
         IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
         ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}"/>


public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {  
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyItemType> _myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItemType>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyItemType> MyItems
    {
        get { return _myItems; }
        set { _myItems = value; }
    }

    private MyItemType _mySelectedItem;
    public MyItemType MySelectedItem
    {
        get { return _mySelectedItem; }
        set { _mySelectedItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem"); }
    }

    private void ListBox_selectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_mySelectedItem);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I modified my code behind. But myselectedItem is still empty.

Comment: private ObservableCollection<string> _myItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> MyItems
        {
            get { return _myItems; }
            set { _myItems = value; }
        }

Comment: private string mySelectedItem;
        public string MySelectedItem
        {
            get { return mySelectedItem; }
            set { mySelectedItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
            }
        }

Comment: private void ListBox_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mySelectedItem);
        }

Comment: that is because `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event is intercepting the selection of the `ListBox` use `SelectionChanged` event instead, I updated the example above